# Data Driven framework with Eclipse in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to automate login page with excelsheet approach in which I have set the path resource file and DataDriver but it's showing error. kindly refer attached screenshot. can anyone help me.

**code: DDTXLS.robot**

```
*** Settings ***

Library           SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Resources/Login_resources.robot

Library          DataDriver     ../TestData/LoginData.xls

Suite Setup  Login_resources.Start TestCase

Suite Teardown   Login_resources.Finish TestCase

Test Template   Invalid login


*** Test Cases ***

LoginTestwithExcelFile       ${username}       ${password}
       

*** Keywords ***
  
Invalid login
    [Arguments]     ${username}     ${password}
    Input username      ${username}
    Input pass      ${password}
    Click login button
```

**Code: Login_resources.robot**

```
*** Settings ***

Library      SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
 
${LOGIN URL}        http://localhost:8100/

${Browser}      chrome

*** Keywords ***

Start TestCase 
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    2s
    Open Browser    ${LOGIN URL}    ${Browser}
    maximize browser window
    Select frame    removeframe
    Sleep  2
    
Finish TestCase
    close all browsers

Open login page
    go to    ${LOGIN URL}

Input username
    [Arguments]    ${username}
    input text    xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input    ${username}

Input pass
    [Arguments]    ${password}
    input text    xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input    ${password}

Click login button
    click element    xpath://*[@id="content"]/app-login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/a
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrco1.png)

Comment: Please spend some time formatting your question for better readability

Comment: i have corrected the formatting.

Comment: Can anyone help me in this